# How to set a custom header using @aws-sdk/client-s3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cloudflare-r2

Cloudflare's R2 has an [extension](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/platform/s3-compatibility/extensions/#cf-create-bucket-if-missing) that prevents a `NoSuchBucket` error, by creating the bucket if it does not exist. To enable it, you're supposed to add a `cf-create-bucket-if-missing`: `true` header on the `PutObject` request. Can this header be set if we're using the [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3) npm package? If so, how?

If the answer is no, is there an alternative workaround that you would recommend?

If it helps, I'm creating a backend nestjs API, and would like to include this header in outgoing requests.

Comment: Take a look at the [middleware example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html#middleware).

Comment: @jarmod Brilliant! This is the answer.

Comment: I'll add an answer and maybe you can review and correct as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS SDK v2 allows you to modify requests via [Middleware](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html#middleware).

Here’s an example of adding a custom header using middleware:

```
const client = new S3({ region: "us-east-1" });

client.middlewareStack.add(
  (next, context) => (args) => {
    args.request.headers["cf-create-bucket-if-missing"] = "true";
    return next(args);
  },
  {
    step: "serialize",
  }
);

const params = {}; // TODO: fill in usual PutObject params

await client.PutObject(params);
```

There's a good article that dives into the middleware stack [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/middleware-stack-modular-aws-sdk-js/).

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I had to change was to set the middleware in the `serialize` step, rather than `build`. While both work for PutObject, the latter would cause my GetObject presigned url's to return a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` Error.